Bose-Einstein statistics: What would the average or expectation value of velocity $\langle v \rangle$ be for an ideal Bose gas?
I would appreciate if anyone could provide me with the general velocity distribution probability density function and compare the same with the Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution.

Velocity or speed?

I understand the confusion, but velocity average might just be 0 by intuition so speed average would make much more sense

I will consider a massive, non relativistic, Bose gas, in the thermodynamic limit and in dimensionless units so that $m=\hbar=k_B=n=1$ (the final variable is particle density). The parameters are temperature $T$ (and its inverse $\beta$) and dimensionality $D$.
Consider first the normal phase i.e. any temperature for $D\leq2$ or above the critical temperature for $D>2$:
$$
\beta_c=\zeta(D/2)^{2/D}
$$
The average distribution per mode is given by BE statistics:
$$
dn=\frac{ze^{-\beta E}}{1-ze^{-\beta E}} \frac{E^{D/2-1}dE}{\Gamma(D/2)}
$$
with the fugacity $z$ defined implicitly by the normalization:
$$
\text{Li}_{D/2}(z) = \beta^{D/2}
$$
Since:
$$
E=\frac{v^2}2
$$
You deduce the pdf of the speed:
$$
dn= \frac{ze^{-\beta v^2/2}}{1-ze^{-\beta v^2/2}} \frac{v^{D-1}dv}{\Gamma(D/2)2^{D/2-1}}
$$
The mean speed is:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle v\rangle &= \int_0^{+\infty} \sqrt{2E}\frac{ze^{-\beta E}}{1-ze^{-\beta E}} \frac{E^{D/2-1}dE}{\Gamma(D/2)} \\
&= \sqrt2\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{D+1}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac D2\right)}\beta^{-(D+1)/2}\text{Li}_{(D+1)/2}(z)
\end{align}
$$
As usual, in the high temperature limit, $\beta\to 0$:
$$
z=\beta^{D/2}\to 0\\
dn= \beta^{D/2}e^{-\beta v^2/2}\frac{v^{D-1}dv}{\Gamma(D/2)2^{D/2-1}}\\
\langle v\rangle=\sqrt{2T} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{D+1}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac D2\right)}
$$
you recover exactly MB statistics.
At lower temperatures, the two models diverge. You can figure things out explicitly at the boundary of the normal phase. For $D>2$:
$$
\langle v\rangle= \sqrt{2T_c} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{D+1}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac D2\right)}\frac{\zeta\left(\frac{D+1}2\right)}{\zeta\left(\frac D2\right)}
$$
the extra zeta ratio captures the discrepancy. In general, the BE statistics redistribute particles to lower energies which is why the mean speed is systematically lower. The differences are even more striking in the BEC phase for $D>2$.
Hope this helps.
